# Problems creating a railtie for a rails ORM gem I'm developing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, orm, redis

I am developing a Ruby gem, Ampere, that acts as an ORM for the Redis database. I am trying to shore up its Rails integration, and was able to tie in an initializer and console hook, but my generators do not work yet. I have a generator, `ampere:config` that installs a default configuration YAML file, and a replacement for the model generator as well.

When I install my gem into a testing Rails app, the `ampere:config` generator shows up in the list when I run `rails generate` on the command line, but when I type `rails g ampere:config`, I get:

```
Could not find generator ampere:config.
```

and nothing else. My generator lives in "lib/rails/generators/config/" within the gem, and clearly Rails knows about it since it showed up in the `rails g` list, but something's not right. If anyone can help or knows of some better documentation for this than the Rails Guides, which are sparse to say the least, it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I finally got this. For the generators to work, they have to call `source_root` with the relative path of their templates, and they have to live in `lib/rails/generators/your_gem_name/`, then the directory structure in `your_gem_name/` is what you'd expect from reading the documentation (or running `rails g generator` in a Rails project).

The documentation is not very clear about this, so it was a bit confusing, but after looking at a few examples I tried this and it worked.